# How to use not static attributes as default values in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

There's classes and schedules. Strictly, one `SchoolClass` to one `Schedule`.
The creation of a `Schedule` depends on a `SchoolClass`, so I decided to inject `SchoolClass` on constructor to constrain the association.

```
class Schedule extends Model
{
    // ...

    private $class;

    public function __construct(SchoolClass $class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    // Used to limit domain, based on the associated class_id
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('class', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('class_id', $this->class->id);
        });
    }

    public function getClassIdAttribute()
    {
        return $this->class->id;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

By this way, I can obtain the `class_id` associated with the Schedule

```
new Schedule(SchoolClass::find(1))->class_id; // Returns 1, as supposed
```

When creating a `Schedule`, associated to a `SchoolClass`, I want that builder consider the `class_id` attribute, but when I try to save it:

```
new Schedule(SchoolClass::find(1))->save(); // General error: 1364 Field 'class_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably not set class_id in the fillable array. If you do that or make an empty guarded array, the error should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't resolve.

Comment: Is there a new error?

Comment: No, I get same error

Comment: Where dit you put the fillable array?

Comment: I used $guarded = [] as Model attribute. Should I try $fillable ?

Comment: In wich class did you put the array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242913/discussion-between-gui-and-stefan).

Comment: The answers provided on StackOverflow should be clear and should not be used to advise or seek help from someone else. Let us know your ideas in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution.

Updating model `$attributes` on the constructor:

```
public function __construct(SchoolClass $class)
{
    $this->class = $class;
    $this->attributes['class_id'] = $class->id;
}
```

So, until now the model wasn't fullfiled with `class_id`, and wasn't considering that field on save() method.

By the way, I believe there will be a better solution.